How to find a file in rpm package and copy it in one command line?
How can I achieve to find and grep a specific file in a rpm package and copy it in one command line execution?
I tried with yum repoquery to look through all files in the rpm package and grep for the specific file. After that I would like to take the result path and copy it to the /tmp folder.
The following command is wrong:
yum repoquery -l rpm_package | grep "specifc/file.txt" -exec cp "{}" /tmp  \;

Resulting in:
grep: specifc/file.txt: File or directory not found
grep: cp: File or directory not found
grep: {}: File or directory not found
grep: /tmp: Is directory
grep: ;: File or directory not found


What do you mean with "wrong"? Please try to isolate the problem, too, so it becomes obvious whether yum or grep is giving you challenges. That said, both tags you applied are wrong, please read their description. You can [edit] your question to fix that and perhaps add "grep" as tag if applicable.

Ok. My question is updated. I had to translate the error messages from German to English.

-exec is a find primitive; you can't pass it to grep or anything else that isn't find.

If you want to extract a file from a RPM, you need to download that RPM. After doing so, you can use rpm2cpio to access it as a cpio archive, which will let you use the same usage you would use to extract a specific file from a cpio archive directly.

I'm installing a rpm package via yum. Then I want to extract one file from the installed yum package and delete the package afterwards again.

Check out xargs, which may help.

Why does it have to be "one command line"?

Because I want to use it in one Ansible task where I extract the file name and copy it to another location. In the same time I register the path to a Ansible variable.

I hope I've understood your question correctly, and this might not be the best solution out there, but here it goes anyway.
My tests were based on the putty.rpm binary package.
There is a command named "rpmdev-extract" (from the rpmdevtools package) that would allow you (as its name implies) to extract the (whole) contents of a RPM, but I didn't find a way to "filter-in" a specific file name.
According to this page, a RPM binary package contains a final payload in cpio format. So, the suggested approach is to use rpm2cpio to extract that payload and feed it to the cpio command, which does allow selecting individual source files based on a given pattern.
Manpage excerpt:
cpio  {-i|--extract} (...) [pattern...] [< archive]

Any non-option command  line arguments  are shell globbing patterns;
only files in the archive whose names match one or more of those
patterns are copied from the archive.

You can query the contents of a RPM package with rpm -q -l name.
In the case of "putty", I want to extract only the file "/usr/share/applications/putty.desktop" from the archive.
Execution:
$ rpm2cpio putty.rpm | cpio -i --to-stdout '*/putty.desktop'
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Putty
Comment=A SSH, Telnet and Rlogin client
Exec=putty
Icon=putty
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=Network;RemoteAccess;
StartupNotify=true
X-Desktop-File-Install-Version=0.26

Trying to extrapolate the above to your specific needs:
rpm2cpio path/to/rpm_package.rpm | cpio -i --to-stdout '*specifc/file.txt' >/tmp/output.txt

Update
If all you want is to find the path where a given file was installed, and copy that file somewhere, you can use xargs as suggested by Ulrich Eckhardt :
rpm -ql rpm_package | grep -m 1 -F 'specific/file.txt' | xargs -d '\n' cp -vt /tmp

... or, if your cp command doesn't understand the -t (target-directory) option :
rpm -ql rpm_package | grep -m 1 -F 'specific/file.txt' | xargs -d '\n' -I '{}' cp -v '{}' /tmp

Hope that helps.
